# How to add/remove tr in a table when checkbox is select/deselect in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I want to add/remove a row in a table when selecting/deselecting a checkbox. The checkbox and table have the same value. For example if a checkbox has value of `2`, the specific row of the table has a value of exactly `2`, and so on.

To clarify better, if you select the checkbox of value `3`, it will add a `tr` in the table and show the value of `2` and if you deselect the checkbox of value `2`, it will remove the `tr` that contains value of `2`.

Below is my code. It works for adding but doesn't work for removing. Any help?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td>value of 1</td>
    <tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="3">
```

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#tbl').append('<tr><td>' + $this.val() + '</td></tr>');
    } else {
        $('#tbl').find('<tr><td>' + $this.val() + '</td></tr>').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work for removing. But you just fail to find the `<tr>` element. If I get you correctly, this code should work.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var $tr = $('<tr />').attr('data-val', val);
        var $td = $('<td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>');

        $tr.append($td);
        $('#tbl').append($tr);
    }
    else {
        $('#tbl').find("[data-val='"+ val +"']").remove();
    }

 });
```

Comment: @John What feature? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: @choz.I add some feature to delete the specific row but it doesn't work.
`var $td=$('<td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>');
$tr.append($td);$('#tbl').append($tr);
<script> $('.fa fa-times').click(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove();});`
unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you put `.fa fa-times`? Can you edit your question and provide full html and script?

Comment: I edited your code and added remove feature. if you click on the fa fa-times, it should remove the specific row. but it doesn't do that

Comment: Where do you put `.fa fa-times` element? Is it inside `<tr>`? Can you edit your question for this or ask the new one?

Comment: as I said before I edited your code. I put the fa fa-times class inside `td`. could you take a look at your answer

Comment: Edit in your question @John.. Post the html that has the `.fa .fa-times`, so that I can understand.

Comment: Ok nvm.. I get it.. Change from `$('.fa fa-times')` to `$('.fa.fa-times')`.. Then it should work..

Comment: @John Post your full code in the question.. Both html and javascript that you're using..

Comment: @John Yes I can see that.. Please avoid editing answers in the future.. You can edit your own question. And, please change `$('.fa .fa-times')` to `$('.fa.fa-times')`.. *(No space)*

Comment: I set it without space but the problem is remained

Comment: @John Let's continue in a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113026/37457371)..

Comment: @I can't continue in this chat room because of my reputation

Comment: @John.. Ups sorry, didn't know that.. Can you edit your own question? And post your full html and javascript? And before that, please have a look at this [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/299Lg96w/)

Comment: I implement table and check box in modal. is it the issue?
I can't insert my code because stack over flow doesn't give me permission because of code styling

Comment: @John Or you can create another question, since its another question. It might be modal issue, but depends where you put your code at. If you can replicate the same issue on fiddle, then it'd be easy to help..

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // write the tr
    $('#tbl').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
  } 
  else {
    // roll over each tr and check text 
    var alltr = $('#tbl').find('tr');
    $(alltr).each(function() {

      if ($(this).text() == val)
        $(this).remove();
    });
  }
});
```